# Use map with return value of soup.select to get table headers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
```

How do I get an array of strings from table headers like

```
soup = Soup(html, features="html.parser")
headers = soup.select("#StatusGrid thead tr").map(lambda x: x.text)
```

Select does not return a list. Can I inspect the type that it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any example of your html it is hard to help, you may can provide an url or some html. However, to generate your list `with map()` put the `list` inside.

Alternativ use a `list comprehension`:

```
[x.text for x in soup.select("#StatusGrid thead tr")]
```

Checking the type will give you `bs4.element.ResultSet`:

```
type(soup.select("#StatusGrid thead tr"))
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html='''
<table id="StatusGrid">
<thead>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
</thead>
</table>
'''

soup = Soup(html, features="html.parser")
list(map(lambda x: x.text, soup.select("#StatusGrid thead tr")))
```

#### Output

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use [**`.stripped_strings`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings)

From the Docs

> `.stripped_strings` yields Python strings that have had whitespace stripped.

Since it returns a `generator` you can convert it to a `list` to have an array of strings.

Here is how to use it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html='''
<table id="StatusGrid">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Heading-1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Heading-2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Heading-3</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
'''

soup = Soup(html, features="lxml")
t = soup.find('table', {'id': 'StatusGrid'}).find('thead')
print(list(t.stripped_strings))
```

```
['Heading-1', 'Heading-2', 'Heading-3']
```

Comment: Another very interesting approach, I have not yet discovered this method.   When I read your example, I was afraid about the "-" and that it would only work for texts without spaces, but that was not the case.  Learned something again. Thanks